# Create a new revisions only at the time of specific state transition

Tags: workflows, nodes

I am using Revisioning and Workflow module along with Drupal 6 to create new states of the node and revisions.Currently if I select 'New revision in draft, pending moderation (requires "Create new revision")' under workflow settings it will create a new revision only when a node is published.But I want it other way.I want to create a new revision only at aspecific state change of my choice.

For e.g. The node is in 'Finally Submitted' state and it is transitioned to 'Moderation' state. At this transition I want to a new revision to be created otherwise not.

How is that achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), You can have something like the below:

```
Event: Workflow state has changed 
If: Workflow state is x (choose your state)
DO: Create a new pending revision of the node
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly answers my question. Now I have to check out how to implement this on multiple nodes from different content type at one go, specially when the nodes are shown through Views inside a Panel